# Search by the field in ElasticSearch in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have objects indexed in elasticsearch:

{"id":"one","name":"John"}
{"id":"two","name":"Steve"}

I put them into elastic with index 'people', type 'human' and document '/id(one,two)/'

The task is to search records by 'name' in java using elasticsearch 6.2.4 with rest high level client.

Here is my code example:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", name));
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("people");
    searchRequest.types("human");
    searchRequest.indices("name").source(sourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse;
    RestHighLevelClient client = getClient();
    searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
```

this is not working.

Need help in performing the search.

Answer (score 3):

Please try below code.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("people"); 
searchRequest.types("human");
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", name"));
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
```

Here `name` must be in lowercase.

Comment: For information - if the field name is 'lastName' - it not works in lowercase ('lastname'), but works as it ('lastName')